# InDesign CS6 Liquid Layout print and mobile Version

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, mobile

I have to design multiple A4 document (always A4 and only one page per document).
these offers shall be downloadable online, so they shall have to be liquid (i guess) to be also mobile readable, without scrolling into it and to get a numb thumb.
So I read a hell of a lot and did´t got an answer, that worked.
So: How do I do it? With the option of an alternative layout? Or with a fluid Layout? And how can I get the text be scaling to a good size?

Thank you for help!!!

Charlotte

Comment: Hey Charlotte, just wanted to welcome you to GD.SE! If you have any questions about how the site works, have a look at the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) or feel free to ping one of us in [Graphic Design Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) once your reputation reaches 20.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a responsive PDF. The whole purpose of a PDF is to look the same no matter what device you're viewing on. A PDF is the final output of the layout.

Your best option is for an alternative download to a revised version of the PDF that works best for mobile. You could probably do some coding in that this device downloads this version of the PDF or just use separate links.

If you want a responsive PDF that is for web only. Then you can create that using HTML and CSS. The downside is you would have to re-create the design using code and need an understanding of web development.

Adding to changing text size based on screen size. You can do this using CSS media queries if going the HTML and CSS route.

Comment: Good answer. I'm just adding a note, not worth it as a new answer. There are server side languages and libraries than can generate diferent pdf depending on what you program on them, but it is really complex, you need to be a good programer. It is not a Graphic design issue anymore. :o) So, a real world answer is what AndrewH posted.